# How to set the initial pose for the robot in navigation?

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I followed the tutorials of navigation , but I meet some problems. I joysticked the robot and used Gmapping to generate a map . Next I turn off the robot and restart it . The laser scan and odometry work well. Then I use that map with AMCL. When I load the map with Map_Sever,the rviz shows that  the robot always stays in the original point of the map by defalut although the robot is in other places actually.I donot know how to set the initial pose for the robot . Can the robot match the laser date with the environment of the map and make itself localized autonomously ? Or do I need to set the initialpose for the robot manully?
Any suggestion will be appreciated!Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144596/how-to-set-the-initial-pose-for-the-robot-in-navigation?/) by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having the robot figure out where it is on startup is known as the "kidnapped robot problem" in robotics. AMCL does not solve it, so you'll have to set the pose manually or find a different localization package that does solve this problem.

You can set the robot's pose manually using the "2D Pose Estimate" tool in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-09-27**:
Is there a solution for this in ROS? It's something I would like my robot to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL provides the "global_localization" service for this use case (see [AMCL wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Services)). It disperses particles randomly in the given map and hopefully finds the correct robot pose after the robot moved around a little bit, pruning "bad" particles. You´ll have to test how well that works for your scenario, though. I haven´t played around with it much, but I´d expect that huge and redundant looking environment (e.g. with lot of places looking the same) will be a challenge. If you are able to set the initial_pose, that definitely would be the more reliable method.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-02-07**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher - Thanks for the answer. I was thinking about creating a Wi-Fi map using odometry along with a gmapping map. And then use the x,y co-ordinate from the Wi-Fi map as input to initial position to the gmapping map. I can get the Wi-Fi x,y coordinates based on the Wi-Fi id at that pnt

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-02-07**:
Do you have any suggestions about accomplishing that? How can I create a 2D map using odometry and the Wi-Fi unique ID at that particular point in that map. If a map won't be possible then I was thinking about  a 2D array containing a unique ID as the value and x,y as the indices. Any thoughts?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2017-02-07**:
@pallavbakshi, it would be better if you create a new question with your doubts and reference this one. Bear in mind that this is actually an old question, already marked as answered, so you will get better visibility creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the method to automatically position the robot on the map. (Alternative of 2D pose button)

Open RViz. Using pose estimate position the robot to the required pose.

rostopic echo /amcl_pose

note x and y of posotion

pose:
pose:
position:
x: 0.2692
y: 0.0218
z: 0.0

give x as initial x pose
give y as initial y pose

add these values as the arguments initial_pose_x, initial_pose_y
In my case orientation was not needed(so I have not tried changing orientation)

So from the next time when we load gazebo+amcl, the mobile robot automatically positions itself on the map. So no need to manually set the home pose using 2D pose estimate button once initial pose arguments are set.

---

Originally posted by [Sanjuna Mariam Mathews](https://answers.ros.org/users/52804/sanjuna-mariam-mathews/) with karma: 51 on 2020-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1